How to fix altair transform_filter()?
I'm trying to create a choropleth map of the US displaying the percentages of the population with different disabilities. However, using the drop-down selection tool bar makes the data/color of the states disappear.
image
Here is my code:
states = alt.topo_feature(data.us_10m.url, feature = 'states')

base_map = alt.Chart(states).mark_geoshape(
    fill='lightgray',
    stroke='white'
).properties(
    width=800,
    height=500
).project('albersUsa')

selection = alt.selection_point(
   fields=['Response'],
   bind=alt.binding_select(options = disability_options, name='Select disability type')
)

choropleth = alt.Chart(states).mark_geoshape().encode(
   color=alt.condition(
        selection,
        alt.Color('Data_Value:Q'),
        alt.value('lightgray')
    ),
    tooltip=['LocationDesc:N', 'Data_Value:Q']
).add_params(selection
).transform_filter(
    selection
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='id', 
    from_=alt.LookupData(df_2021, key='LocationID', fields=['LocationDesc','Data_Value'])
).properties(
    title='Choropleth Map of Disability Data (2021)'
)

base_map+choropleth


Make sure that you have data for the states that disappear in df_2021 and double check that the ID is the same. If that doesn't do it, include example data and how you define df_2021 and disability_options so that others can copy paste your code to reproduce the issue
